# Intersection of coproduct in pointed categories.

Tags: category-theory

Let $M_i:i\in I$ a family of object in a pointed category. We assume the existence of all intersections and coproducts considered below.
The question is: is true that for any subsets $X,Y\subseteq I$
$$\Big(\coprod_{i\in X} M_i\Big)\cap\Big(\coprod_{i\in Y} M_i\Big)=\coprod_{i\in X\cap Y} M_i$$?

The inclusion $\supseteq$ seem to be valid even without a zero object.

Here my attempt for a possible proof for the $\subseteq$ inclusion.
Let $f:\coprod_{i\in I}M_i\to\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$ which is the inclusion $M_i\to\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$ if $i\in X$ and the zero $M_i\to\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$ if $i\notin X$. Then $f$ is a retraction for the inclusion $\coprod_{i\in X} M_i\to \coprod_{i\in I} M_i$.
Thus the inclusion:
$$\Big(\coprod_{i\in X} M_i\Big)\cap\Big(\coprod_{i\in Y} M_i\Big)\to\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$$
can be written as:
$$\Big(\coprod_{i\in X} M_i\Big)\cap\Big(\coprod_{i\in Y} M_i\Big)\to\coprod_{i\in X} M_i\to\coprod_{i\in I} M_i\xrightarrow{f}\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$$
which is the same to
$$\Big(\coprod_{i\in X} M_i\Big)\cap\Big(\coprod_{i\in Y} M_i\Big)\to\coprod_{i\in Y} M_i\to\coprod_{i\in I} M_i\xrightarrow{f}\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$$
and 
The restriction of $f$ to $\coprod_{i\in Y} M_i$, $f$ reduces to the inclusion $M_i\to\coprod_{i\in I} M_i$ if $i\in X\cap Y$ and the zero $M_i\to\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$ if $i\in Y\setminus X$. Consequently, the morphism
$$\coprod_{i\in Y} M_i\to\coprod_{i\in I} M_i\xrightarrow{f}\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$$
factors throughout the inclusion $\coprod_{i\in X\cap Y} M_i\to\coprod_{i\in X} M_i$.

Comment: Have you considered example categories?

Comment: Coproduct insertions may not be monic, intersections may not commute with coproducts, etc. etc.

Comment: Coproducts insertions are split monic since we are in the pointed setting.

Comment: I think that the assertion in true if $I$ is a finite set and this fact implies that the morphism $A\amalg B\to A\prod B$ has zero kernel. My doubt is in the case $I$ infinite set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lemma*: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, $i : A \to B$ and $p : B \to A$ morphisms with $pi=\mathrm{id}$. Then $e=ip : B \to B$ is idempotent and $i$ is an equalizer of $e$ and $\mathrm{id}_B$.

The proof is easy. Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be a pointed category with coproducts (which I will denote as $\oplus$), $(M_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of objects in $\mathcal{C}$ and $X,Y \subseteq I$. Consider the inclusion $i_X : \bigoplus_{i \in X } M_i \to \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$ and the projection $p_X : \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i \to \bigoplus_{i \in X} M_i$ (which is $0$ on each $M_i$ with $i \in I \setminus X$). We have $p_X i_X = \mathrm{id}$, so that the Lemma is applicable.

Since limits commute with limits, we see that $\bigoplus_{i \in X} M_i \cap \bigoplus_{i \in Y} M_i$ is the equalizer of $\mathrm{id} : \bigoplus_{i \in Y} M_i \to \bigoplus_{i \in Y} M_i$ and $e_X : \bigoplus_{i \in Y} M_i \to \bigoplus_{i \in Y} M_i$, and hence $\bigoplus_{i \in X \cap Y} M_i$ by another application of the Lemma.

Comment: This confirm that the assertion holds also in the infinite case.